# RTL support in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, right-to-left, rtlcss

Bootstrap helps to target both `rtl` and `ltr` directions by giving classes like `ms-auto`, `me-auto` which translate to corresponding `margin-left` and `margin-right` based on the direction used.

I am trying to use bootstrap for my project to support both `rtl` and `ltr` direction texts. The way currently bootstrap suggests to do this is very complex which involves using RTL CSS.

What i don't understand is when there are css properties like `margin-inline-start` which automatically applies margin based on direction, why is bootstrap still using `margin-right` / `margin-left`. Are there any cases `margin-inline-start` and similar css properties can fail? Or is this just an issue with bootstrap?

Comment: i don't understand well your question (is lack of code and [mcve] would be helpful) but margin-inline-start dependis on the element's writing mode

Comment: @Sfili_81 Thanks for your interest. Actually there is no issue here to reproduce. I just wanted to know why bootstrap doesn't use `margin-inline-start/end` which seems to work well (so far) for me. Writing Mode: Yes there are certain things that effect margin-inline-start/end, but isn't that the plus point here? Based on direction, writing mode etc margins, paddings are automatically applied as required.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason in a Issue on bootstrap github [Issue Link](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/32330#issuecomment-781682668).

There seems to be many places such changes have to be made, so they are differing it until changes are made in all the places. Bootstrap 6 might have this.